# What is the correct size of fuse for a Igloo Iceless cooler? DC 12v 55w, Stock Fuse 250V 7.5A

Tags: heat, fuses, cooling

I would like to know if the stock fuse is too big for the cooler, because the original cable to come with the cooler melted at the 12v plug. The plastic around the tip was melted to the point the tip doesn't move anymore.

And the new cable I order has over heating issue too. Just pulling it out after some use time, and you can feel the heat from it.

So is the over heating issue from having a over size fuse or something else?

I just want to have a ice chest for my drinks for work chilled, without worrying that the cable will cause a fire.

Comment: The fuse is there to protect the cable from melting in case there is a short circuit. The device will pull any amount of current it needs to work, so putting in a fuse with smaller ratings will do nothing, unless the fuse rating is too low and it melts under normal use.

Answer (score 1):

A 7.5 A fuse for something that draws ~4.6 A (55W/12V) sounds about right.  The problem is probably at the plug end of the cable, or the 12 V outlet (cigarette lighter?).  Dirty contacts would increase the resistance there and so increase the power dissipation and heat.

Comment: cigarette lighter plug still gets hot when in use, I just don't want to have spend $30 on a new cable every time it melts because of the heat.